# How do you attach another server to Windows Server 2012 essentials?

Tags: remote-access, windows-server-2012, dashboard

My primary server is setup as a Windows Server 2012 Essentials.

I have another server running Windows Server 2012 Standard and I would like to show it via the Dashboard that I get from Essentials. I see that there is a connector for Windows 7/8 clients, but is there an equivalent for servers? I have already joined the server to the domain.

[image: Server Essentials Dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

Just run the connector.  It will place the server in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't done this myself, I may be able to point you to some useful articles.

The procedure as described in this article may help (although for 2008 R2) :
[Remote Desktop Services in Windows 2008 R2 – Part 3 – RD Web Access & RemoteApp](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/remote-desktop-services-windows-2008-r2-part-3-web-access-remoteapp/).

It describes how to use the Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration to configure each RD Session Host Server that will become a farm member in the RD Connection Broker.

The article [No farm apps in RD Web Access](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverTS/thread/487647a4-acd7-43e1-828c-7c64a857bdfe) also contains lots of useful links.

Just to remark that my own attempt to use Windows Server 2012 Essentials
terminated with my going back to 2008 R2.